# How to pass LaTeX code through a variable to pdflatex in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, escaping, shell-exec, pdflatex

I tried this:
(.php file)

```
<?php
$texscript = "
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmargin=.8cm,vmargin=1.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\rhead{{\large\bfseries\thepage}}
\rhead{{\fbox{\large\bfseries\thepage}}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\multido{}{1383}{\vphantom{x}\newpage}
\end{document}
";

$pdflatex = shell_exec("echo \$PATH > myenv; pdflatex ".$texscript." ");
?>
```

and am getting an error:

> pdflatex : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex) restricted \write18 enabled. ** ! End of file on the terminal...

why?

Is the above given code the correct way to write LaTeX in PHP variables and pass it to `pdflatex` command??
If not, then plz suggest corrections!
I don't want to call an external `.tex` file but write the LaTeX code in PHP file itself and run from there.

Comment: 1. the code in `""` (couble quotes) needs to be escaped or you use `''` (single quotes) instead.
2. pdflatex expects either a file or input by pipe like `cat t.tex | pdflatex`
3. try to steer output towards another directory where you have rights to write with `-output-directory` option for `pdflatex` command. or give right to write on he very same directory the

Comment: also consider updating if possible as your version is more than a year old already

Comment: i tried single quotes..still gives the same error

Comment: Actually, it runs fine if i provide an external .tex file containing the same latex code.

Comment: parameters file and string is not the same. just try to do it on cli: `pdflatex $(cat t.tex )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping may be one part, another is calling the command `pdflatex`; I circumvented (first) by writing the file before and (second) by replacing comments and newline on the variable so `pdflatex` has no problem with it any longer…

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$texscript = '\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmargin=.8cm,vmargin=1.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\rhead{{\large\bfseries\thepage}}
\rhead{{\fbox{\large\bfseries\thepage}}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\multido{}{1383}{\vphantom{x}\newpage}
\end{document}
';

//write code to file
$fn="texfile.tex";
$myfile = fopen($fn, "w");
fwrite($myfile, $texscript);
fclose($myfile);

//then execute pdflatex with parameter
//didnt need
//echo $PATH > myenv;
$pdflatex = shell_exec('pdflatex ' .$fn .'' );

//var_dump( $pdflatex );
//test for success
if (!file_exists("texfile.pdf")){
    print_r( file_get_contents("texfile.log") );
} else {
    echo "PDF crated from file\n";
}

//trying same without file
//removed comments and newlines
$texscript = preg_replace('/[ \t]*\%.*[ \t]*[\r\n]+/', '', $texscript);
$texscript = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '', $texscript);
//ahve a look on the variable
//var_dump($texscript);

$pdflatex = shell_exec('pdflatex "' .$texscript.'"' );
if (!file_exists("article.pdf")){
    print_r(  file_get_contents("article.log") );
} else {
    echo "PDF created from String\n";
}    

?>
```

it shouldn't matter to write the tex-file as well as pdflatex will write files besides the desired PDF.

also added regex for replacing comments/newline.

I call the script with: `php test.php` on cli with GNU/Linux Debian 8

this produces the output:

```
PDF crated from file
string(405) "\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\usepackage{helvet}\usepackage{times}\usepackage{multido}\usepackage{fancyhdr}\usepackage[hmargin=.8cm,vmargin=1.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}\begin{document}\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{{\fbox{\large\bfseries\thepage}}}\setcounter{page}{1}\multido{}{1}{\vphantom{x}\newpage}\end{document}"
PDF created from String
```

and the PDF files both work and have the same filesize:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 vv01f vv01f 3360 Mai  5 article.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 vv01f vv01f 3360 Mai  5 texfile.pdf
```

Comment: Well, thanks.. it works.. but i don't want to write it into a .tex file but directly pass the latex code through a php var..

Comment: works – even without writing to file before – after removing comments and newlines plus adding double quotes for the call to `shell_exec`

Comment: well, the many spaces in output tell me: you did not run the code above. there are not that whitespaces; also you abuse the answer-function.

Comment: Well i did run the code above and am getting the same output as i have posted below.. also var_dump($texscript); is also giving output with spaces and not like what u r getting..

Comment: Also I have no intentions of abusing anything .. its just that I am using stackoverflow for the first time.. and am desperately trying to get things to work..that's it..will try to use it properly next time..

Comment: did you try it manually on cli like `pdflatex "\documentclass{article}\begin{document}test\end{document}"` resp. `pdflatex "\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\usepackage{helvet}\usepackage{times}\usepackage{multido}\usepackage{fancyhdr}\usepackage[hmargin=.8cm,vmargin=1.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}\begin{document}\fancyhf{} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{{\fbox{\large\bfseries\thepage}}}\setcounter{page}{1}\multido{}{1383}{\vphantom{x}\newpage}\end{document}"`. if some part doesnt work, you have to identify by separation.